# Second spring profile in java_options

Tags: spring, kubernetes-helm

I use Teamcity, Helm and Spring.
i have param in TC java_opts =

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=feature,audit 
-Xmx%app.java.max_heap% ...
```

in helm chart i have deployment.yaml with

```
           env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: "{{ .Values.java_opts }}"
```

I expected spring to initialize the context with two profiles: feature and audit. But in log i see

```
2020-07-27 18:03:09.949 [main] [] INFO  r.t.b.priestback.PriestBackApplicationKt - The following profiles are active: feature
```

How add second profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's bad parsing in Helm
https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1556
i change on

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=feature\,audit
```